# How to make some cells in DataGrid column editable, while leaving others read-only?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got following table:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Websites}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Website" Binding="{Binding Uri}"/>             
        </DataGrid.Columns>         
    </DataGrid>
```

I would like for the user to not to be able to edit the first 15 rows, and to be able to edit everything else.

What is the best way of doing this?